# In ggplot, is there a way to change the axis tick labels if they are already numeric?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to change the name of ticks on an axis on a scatter plot made by ggplot.  I want to change numeric tick marks on the X and Y axis to strings, but it instead just deletes the tick mark labels entirely.  My code:

```
ggplot(anes_final, aes(x = V201617x, y = V202072)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("1" = "$0 - $5000", "2" = "$5000 - $10,000", "3" = "$10,000 - $12,500", "4" = "$12,500 - $15,000", "5" = "$15,000 - $17,500", "6" = "$17,500 - $20,000", "7" = "$20,000 - $22,500", "8" = "$22,500 - $25,000", "9" = "$25,000 - $27,500", "10" = "$27,500 - $30,000", "11" = "$30,000 - $35,000", "12" = "$35,000 - $40,000", "13" = "$40,000 - $45,000", "14" = "$45,000 - $50,000", "15" = "$50,000 - $55,000", "16" = "$55,000 - $60,000", "17" = "$60,000 - $65,000", "18" = "$65,000 - $70,000", "19" = "$70,000 - $75,000", "20" = "$75,000 - $80,000", "21" = "$80,000 - $90,000", "22" = "$90,000 - $100,000", "23" = "$100,000 - $110,000", "24" = "$110,000 - $125,000", "25" = "$125,000 - $150,000", "26" = "$150,000 - $175,000", "27" = "$175,000 - $250,000", "28" = "over $250,000")) + scale_y_discrete(labels=c("1" = "Yes",  "2" = "No")) + ggtitle("Voted in the Presidential election versus Household Income") +
 xlab("Income bracket") + ylab("Voted in election")
```

[Image of scatter plot if I don't apply scale_x_discrete and scale_y_discrete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPvRr.png)

[Image of scatter plot after applying the scale_x_discrete and scale_y_discrete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTFcT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Change the x values to characters in aes

```
aes(x = as.character(V201617x), y = V202072)
```

2. change scale_x_discrete to

```
scale_x_continuous
```

Plot will look different based on which method you use, where #2 will set up the grid first as continuous, with ticks between discrete values and #1 setting up the grid as discrete from the start.